# Post data via jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to post data to my table using AJAX, I have the following form,

```
<form>
    Total <input type="text" id="total" name="total" /><br />
    Bill name<input type="text" id="bill-name" name="bill-name" /><br />
    bill descriptiion <input type="text" id="bill-description" name="bill-description" /><br />
    bill colour<input type="text" id="bill-colour" name="bill-colour" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="insertBill();" />
</form>
```

And my AJAX code is as...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function insertBill()
{
    var bill = $("#bill").val();
    $.post('insert_bill.php', {total: total, bill-name: bill-name, bill-description: bill-description, bill-colour: bill-colour}, function(data) 
    {
        $("#bills").html(data); 
    });
}
</script>
```

For some reason however my values aren't being passed. I'm new to AJAX and so I've been following a tutorial so excuse my naivety! How do I make this work?

Comment: Also, in your function you are calling a form with id `bill`. Edit your form tag, and add this id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this and so many other PHP, jQuery ajax problems, I highly recommend [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) try this:

```
<div id="bills"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function insertBill()
{
    $.post('insert_bill.php', $('form').serialize(), 
        function(data) {
        $("#bills").html(data); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript variables haven't been defined yet. Your javascript function doesn't know about the form.

Try something like this:

```
$.post('insert_bill.php', {total: $('#total').val(), bill-name: $('#bill-name').val()...
```

Or you can set your variables beforehand

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function insertBill()
{
  var total = $('#total').val();
```

I'm not sure what this is doing though:

```
var bill = $("#bill").val();
```

I don't see any id="bill"

Answer (score 0):

You are passing variables that are not even defined. You need to define all your post variables like you did with `var bill = $("#bill").val();` and then pass them.

I would recommend you to use [this](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) jQuery plugin that does everything for you. I use it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `form` tag to this(or something similar)

```
<form id="bill" onsubmit="return insertBill();">
```

and in your function, do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function insertBill() {
    var bill = $("#bill").val();
    $.post('insert_bill.php', {total: total, bill-name: bill-name, bill-description: bill-description, bill-colour: bill-colour}, function(data) 
      {
        $("#bills").html(data); 
      } );
    return true;     // So that form may proceed.
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the missing values, `bill-name` is not a valid identfier, if you really want to use `bill-name` you should wrap it in quotes and retrieve the value using jQuerys [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$.post('insert_bill.php',{ 'bill-name' : $('#bill-name').val() } ....
```